# Problems with characters and loops in c

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, character, do-while

Im writing a program with nested loops and within those loops i ask the user to enter a integer to select which style of looping he/she wants ie: 1 = while loop, 2 = do-while loop, 3 for loop, 4 quit program, then when the user enter which loop he wants it ask how much dots he/she wants to print. My problem is if the user enters a character it goes in to looping without stoping how can i fix that?

```
`do{`
`printf("Choose a loop type to demonstrate\n");`
`printf("   1   while loop\n   2   do-while loop\n` 
`3   for      loop\n   4   quit the program\n"); `                      
`printf("\nEnter your choice: ");`
`scanf("%d%c", &a, &word);`
`if ((a>=5) || (a<=0)|| (a==word))`
`{printf("Please enter a valid menu choice.\nValid Menu choice are 1, 2, 3 or 4\n");`
`}`
 `}while ((a!=1) && (a!=2) && (a!=3)&&(a!=4)); `
```

Comment: can you provide your code snippet. It may be possible as soon as user enters his choice for loop you code jumps into the looping statements, ask for number of dots after you are asking for loop choice and before jumping to looping.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing a bit your test could help you solve this. Just include `#include <ctype.h>` and change :

```
if ((a>=5) || (a<=0)|| (a==word))
```

to

```
if ((a>=5) || (a<=0)|| (isalpha(a)))
```

And

```
 }while ((a!=1) && (a!=2) && (a!=3)&&(a!=4));
```

to

```
 }while ((a!=1) && (a!=2) && (a!=3)&&(a!=4)&&(isalpha(a)));
```

You now test is entered value is a char.This will do the trick !